# Best solution for private video database

Tags: php, html, database, web-applications, video

I am a senior computer engineering student and have an organization that has asked me to create a private video management system for them. They are against storing their videos on YouTube even with them marked as private.

The system would need to be accessible to various users via a web interface. The organization has ample web server space to store videos.

My idea is to create a simple PHP driven web page that accesses a database that contains links to videos stored on the server. My question is if there is a better solution or approach for the interface/back-end or if this is the best way to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the problem - "video management system" could mean a lot of different things, and the solution you've described only really addresses storage. If the end user has no access to the server where the videos are stored, they won't be able to follow the links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ready-made systems for that like [Kaltura](http://www.kaltura.org/), which I have used in the past. While I wouldn't recommend Kaltura specifically for its code quality or ease-of-customizability, it may serve you.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't want the videos on youtube then storing them on their local server is the best idea, like you've stated. With this in mind you'll then have to implement the security for who can access which videos on their side and it only makes sense to store all this information via the database. This will make it easy to join tables based on user logged in, security role and videos stored to display what they need. I think you're definitely on the right page for creating this project. You're doing exactly what I'd do.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration the overall goal of the site, having a php database driven application  is the best option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like Drupal and it's 'video' module. This allows you to quickly set up a site (private, of course) where members can upload videos (and view, download...).
If you *considered* youtube, this means they are not interested in the original video file, but the content of the video itself. Otherwise, you might simply use FTP :))